# Why are Kuwabara and Yusuke's uniforms different from other students?

Tags: yu-yu-hakusho

In YuYu Hakusho its possible to see that Yusuke wears a green uniform and Kuwabara a light blue uniform.  Nobody else wears uniforms like that in their school.

Is there an explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably the case of [Transfer Student Uniforms](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TransferStudentUniforms) as described on Tv Tropes:

> New Transfer Students in places where school uniforms are a cultural default setting often wear their old ones until the school can provide them with a new one. **In fiction, this shows the newcomer or outsider**. When they get the current school uniform, this indicates they've been assimilated. If the student is meant to be a Fish out of Water, they will keep their old uniform throughout the series. In Japanese media, even rebels don't choose to abandon uniforms entirely; in American media they will do this even if the new school doesn't have uniforms. Compare the Non-Uniform Uniform.

And on that same page, it describes the incident in Yu Yu Hakusho (note Kuwabara's case):

> Yusuke from YuYu Hakusho distinct green uniform annoys the faculty, since while technically acceptable he wears it just to stand out. Even Kuwabara wears a slightly different shade of blue than the standard uniform. **This is anime-only, though; manga color images usually have Kuwabara and Yusuke's uniforms matching**, even if the colors aren't always consistent, unless the artist was color-coding them. Keiko calls Yusuke on his green uniform in the dub, but the original doesn't really mention it.

It happens in a lot of other anime/manga as well, commonly enough to be considered a well known trope.